# ESP8266WiFi.hで1KB超のHTTP_GETが出来ない場合 ネットワークのMTU値/MSSの確認

Tags: arduino

ESP-WROOM-02をArduino IDE 1.6.5でプログラムする環境において、サンプルスケッチのESP8266WiFi/WiFiClient.ino サンプルを流用してJSON文字列をHTTPでGETするプログラムを書いているのですが、レスポンスヘッダを含めて1360bytes程度までしか取得できず困っています。

一定以上の大きさのリソースは取得できないという制限があるのならば、Web側でCGIなりで加工する実装に切り替えようと思いますが、この1360bytesの制限を変更する方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただければありがたく存じます。

スケッチは以下のようになります。

```c
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid     = "your-ssid";
const char* password = "your-password";
const char* host = "example.com";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }
}

void loop() {
  delay(5000);
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 80;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  String url = "/hugedata.json";
  Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
  Serial.println(url);
  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  delay(10);
  while(client.available()){
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\r');
    Serial.print(line);
  }
}
```

（2015-11-07 02:40追記）アクセス先のVPSサーバでtcpdumpをとったりして試したところ、eth0のMTUを1500から1400（＝MSS：1360）にしたところ、大きなファイルでもESP-WROOM-02でも8KBのファイルがGETできたので、ESP8266WiFi.hではなくて、回線の問題になると思います。ネットワーク環境を調整して引き続き調査しています。

（2015-11-07 03:24追記）tcpdumpの3way hand shakeの様子を見ていると、我が家の回線がCATVでMTU=1400のところを、ESP-WROOM-02からのSYNでMSS=1380を要求していました。

- アクセス先のサーバがMTU=1500（MSS=1460）のときは、SYN+ACKでMSS=1460が提示され、結果としてMSS=1380（MTU=1420）が採用、サーバからCATV回線にパケットが通らないという状態。
- アクセス先のサーバがMTU=1400（MSS=1360）のときは、SYN+ACKでMSS=1360が提示され、結果としてMSS=1360（MTU=1400）が採用、サーバからCATV回線にパケットが通る。

という切り分けができました。よって、問題は、自宅内のネットワーク環境で、ESP-WROOM-02がMTU=1420（MSS=1380）を採用する原因を調査することになりました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決しました。

まず、追記で書いたCATV回線のMTU値ですが、実際には1420でした。
そして、以前自宅の外から出るWAN回線として使っていたWiMAXのMTU値が1400でした。

- 自宅内ルータは回線が物理的に3回線つながっています。LAN1が自宅内LAN、LAN2がCATV回線によるWAN回線、LAN3がWiMAXルータによるWAN回線です。
- 今まではLAN3のWiMAXをWAN回線として使っていました。
- 自宅内ルータの設定をWiMAXに合わせてインタフェースすべてをMTU 1400に設定していました。
- 最近通常使用のWAN回線をWiMAXからCATV回線に変更しました。
- MTU は1400のままでした。

以上のような環境で、

- ルータのMSS書き換えで、CATV回線から外に出るとき、SYNのMSSが1380に（1420-40）
- 3way hand shakeで、MSSとして1380が採用（MTU 1420：CATV回線は通る）
- MTUを1400としていたため、GETリクエストの戻りデータが1360byte超えるとMTUの1400の制限に引っ掛かりルータの中に入ってこない

となっていました。

解決法として、まだWiMAX回線をWANに切り替える可能性があるため、

- すべての回線のMSS書き換えを1360に設定

しました。

これにより、ESP-WROOM-02からのSYNパケットもMSS 1360を要求するようになり、1360bytes以上のデータも正常に分割され、レスポンスとして8KB程度のJSON文書も受信できるようになりました。